# Getting invalid message error: list index out of range in discord.py 2.0 version

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Here is the code

````
    async def on_message(self, message):
 
        if message.author == self.bot.user:
            return

      
        if message.attachments and message.author.id == 646937666251915264:
            
            attachment = message.attachments[0]
         
            if attachment.filename.lower().endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif')):
             
                img_bytes = await attachment.read()
               
                img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img_bytes))
                
                width, height = 500, 500
                img = img.resize((width, height))
            
                img = img.convert('L')
          
                text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
             
                await message.channel.send(f"```{text}```")
````

I was using old version of discord.py and after shifting to new version I getting error. Pls help me to fix this.

Comment: Have you verified the contents of `message.attachments`?

Comment: Yes. Contents of attachment are correct

Comment: Then on which line is the error occurring? What is the full traceback?

Comment: `Invalid message error: list index out of range` only this error coming when I send msg with attachment

Comment: which line ? where ?  the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If the error really is occurring at `attachment = message.attachments[0]`, then `message.attachments` must be an empty list. I can't think of any other reason you would get `list index out of range` otherwise. Try printing `message.attachments`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord.py defines a message attachment as:

attachments¶
A list of attachments given to a message. If Intents.message_content is not enabled this will always be an empty list unless the bot is mentioned or the message is a direct message.

You line that reads:

```
if message.attachments and message.author.id == 646937666251915264:
```

You are setting parameters. The issue is discord always returns attachments list, however it will be empty if there's no attachment, so at your line:

```
attachment = message.attachments[0]
```

The index (which you have set to 0) can return null. You need to change the first line I mentioned to something more like:

```
if len(message.attachments) > 0 and message.author.id == 646937666251915264:
```

This checks is the length of the list is more that 0. As previously mentioned discord messages always have an attachments list, if that list is empty it will still pass through the filter you have set. So you need to check if theres actually contents in that list. This is the reason for you index error.